# Unity3D values disappear from custom editor when starting game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem when changing values and trying to play game these values disappear. For example, if I enable bool in editor and the start game bool disables itself. I use custom editor to change these values.

This is my settings script and [system.serializable] doesn't help:

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Settings : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static bool testMode;
    public static string androidUnitID;
    public static string iphoneUnitID;
}
```

And this is my editor script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Settings))]
class TestEditor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {

        GUILayout.Label("Settings", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        Settings.testMode = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Test Mode", Settings.testMode);
        Settings.androidUnitID = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Android UnitID", Settings.androidUnitID);
        Settings.iphoneUnitID = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Android UnitID", Settings.iphoneUnitID);

}
```

First I'm changing values on editor:

[image: Editor]

Then when play mode is active all values disappear:

[image: Play mode]

Is there any way to fix this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you know you have a . at the end of `Settings.settings` in the line `Settings.settings. = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Test Mode", Settings.testMode);`, in regards to your question can you explain it a little bit better?  Are you saying that you set these values in your editor script, but when you start the game the values change?  Are you sure you have nothing else changing those values anywhere?  since they are static and all objects will reference the same one.

Comment: Thank you for help. I made a mistake when I was rewriting code, everything is working without problem. The thing is that values are not changed anywhere but still values disappear. I've added some pictures to get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity doesn't support serialising static variables "out-of-the-box" (you *can* rewrite the serialisation to accommodate it, but effort vs. reward and all that). So, based on that, what you're essentially seeing is the values that you're setting being stored in the class during Edit, but when Unity goes into Play mode, all the class are re-initialised, deserialised and prepared for game-play. Your static values are lost.

It's the same reason why changed values during game play aren't kept when you go back the other way to Edit mode. Edit mode and Play mode are essentially two separate processes.

Your best bet here would be to create a `ScriptableObject`, with those fields you've marked as static in your `Settings` class, create a reference to the new `ScriptableObject`, and then, if you want, modify the values directly from the ScriptableObject.

Something along the lines of:

```
[CreateAssetMenu ( fileName = "Settings", menuName = "Settings/Create Settings SO", order = 1 )]
public class SettingsScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
  public bool testMode;
  public string androidUnitID;
  public string iphoneUnitID;
  //... Any further configuration/settings items you want should go here.
}
```

You would then modify your `Settings` class:

```
public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
  public SettingsScriptableObject SettingsSO;
}
```

And your editor script:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Settings))]
class TestEditor : Editor
{
  public override void OnInspectorGUI()
  {
    if ( target == null ) return;
    var settings = target as Settings;
        GUILayout.Label("Settings", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        settings.SettingsSO.testMode = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Test Mode", settings.SettingsSO.testMode);
        settings.SettingsSO.androidUnitID = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Android UnitID", settings.SettingsSO.androidUnitID);
        settings.SettingsSO.iphoneUnitID = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Android UnitID", settings.SettingsSO.iphoneUnitID);
  }
}
```

There's [an excellent video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) at Unity about the Edit and Play modes, and how ScriptableObjects can be used to overcome the serialisation problem.